# Symfony routing optional pagination (/test/[1]) vs. slug (/test/abc)

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I've got a controller with two actions and similar URL patterns, but I can't get it work. The following is just a small example. What I want to do is a listAction with (optional) pagination (/test/[1]) and a showAction with alphanumeric ID (/test/abc).

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test/{var}", requirements={"var" = "\d+"}, defaults={"var"=1}, name="app_testint")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function testIntAction($var)
    {
        return new Response(__METHOD__ . ' var=' . $var);
    } 

    /**
     * @Route("/test/{var}", requirements={"var" = "\s+"}, name="app_teststr")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function testStrAction($var)
    {
        return new Response(__METHOD__ . ' var=' . $var);
    }
}
```

With my configuration I only can call the URL with an numeric value. The routes with out and with a string are not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reg-ex for second route is not valid should be `\w+` to match with string. Otherwise you are trying to match with blank spaces.

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{var}", requirements={"var" = "\w+"}, name="app_teststr")
 * @return Response
 */
public function testStrAction($var) {
    return new Response(__METHOD__ . ' var=' . $var);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `:` instead of `=` sign inside the requirements and defaults options:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{var}", requirements={"var": "\d+"}, defaults={"var": 1}, name="app_testint")
 * @return Response
 */

/**
 * @Route("/test/{var}", requirements={"var": "\s+"}, name="app_teststr")
 * @return Response
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    /**
 * @Route("/test/{var}", requirements={"var" = "\d+"}, defaults={"var"=1}, name="app_testint")
 * @return Response
 */
public function testIntAction($var)
{
    return new Response(__METHOD__ . ' var=' . $var);
}

/**
 * @Route("/test/{var}", requirements={"var" = "[A-Za-z]+"}, name="app_teststr")
 * @return Response
 */
public function testStrAction($var)
{
    return new Response(__METHOD__ . ' var=' . $var);
}
```

Can't win with the indentation for some reason. But I replaced your ajax with A-Za-z and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Now I found a for me working solution. Ok, maybe that's a kind of workaround...

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test/", defaults={"var":1})
     * @Route("/test/{var}", requirements={"var":"\d+"}, defaults={"var":null}, name="app_testint")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function testIntAction($var)
    {
        return new Response(__METHOD__ . ' var=' . $var);
    } 

    /**
     * @Route("/test/{var}", name="app_teststr")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function testStrAction($var)
    {
        return new Response(__METHOD__ . ' var=' . $var);
    }
}
```